# Конфликт opentele и telethon

Tags: python, импорт, lib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При использовании двух библиотек возникает куча ошибок как минимум из за того что у них половина функций с одинаковыми названиями, как это можно решить?

Comment: не использовать обе библиотеки? и как вы импортируете модули в своем коде?